# Refresh a label after changing the current keyboard language layout using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to see the current keyboard language when I press (Windows+space) it must normally change the language in the label.
here is the code :

```
public void SetNewCurrentLanguage()
{
    InputLanguage myCurrentLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
    lbl_languuage.Text = "Current input language is: " + myCurrentLanguage.Culture.IetfLanguageTag + '\n';
}
```

and in my `Form_load` I put this :

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetNewCurrentLanguage();
}
```

So, when I change the language it must directly change the language in the label.

I tried to put `lbl_language.Refresh()` but it didn't refresh.
Any help ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why `Refresh`? Just call `SetNewCurrentLanguage` again. This is 100% procedural code, there's noöne to execute it for you.

Comment: but where I call `SetNewCurrentLanguage` again ?

Comment: The same place where you tried to put `Refresh`, I'd expect :)